# How to build apps for ARM-based GPS running Windows CE 5.0?

Tags: windows-ce

After much searching and near pulling my hair out, I'm almost at a dead end.  I am trying to build an application for an older (2002-ish) Magellan GPS device - a RoadMate 2200t, based on an ARM920T processor.

Using Visual Studio 2005, I have attempted to compile a simple app to test, and finally was able to transfer it to the hardware.  It seems to be linked for an x86 architecture though, because I get messages about it not being able to run.

The only way I could find to create apps for this ARM was using "Visual C++ embedded" in VS2005, which does seem to be able to target the ARM9 (at least the ARM9I, not the ARM9T, of which the chip I have is, so I may be hosed there too).  I'd like to use C#, but can't seem to get Visual Studio 2005 to target the ARM architecture.

I have no experience with targeting this platform.  I'd like to ask: firstly, is it possible without proprietary files I'd need from the manufacturer?  Can anyone point me to a tutorial that might shed some light on this not-so-much-seen process?

Thank you for your help
-Dewey

Answer (score 0):

Managed code (C# or .NET) is not processor specific.  You would create a "Smart Device Application" from the new Project menu, build your app, and then deploy that.  You may also need to deploy the Compact Framework runtimes themselves (which *are* processor dependent) but are part of the compiler installs.  I don't have VS '05 installed anywhere, so I can't tell you exactly where they will reside, but likely somewhere along these lines:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\wce400\armv4`

Comment: As a follow-up, I get the sense that deploying for a CE app isn't nearly as simple as an x86 desktop.  I've located the runtimes.  Any idea how I'd figure out where to put them on my device?  I'm having no luck with Windows Mobile Device Center syncing with VS2005, so I have to install everything manually.

Comment: 1. Does Windows Mobile Device Center(WMDC) connect to your device? 2. Do you have Windows Mobile 5.0 sdk installed? Also you may want to look at this project: XOverCE. It gives you a standard Windows CE interface on your device, and should make running custom apps much easier for you.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I can't get WMDC to connect to the device, but I do see the device in Windows device manager  I suspect it's because this was one of the devices made by this mfr. that didn't enumerate as a flash drive and show its contents.  I had to flash a replacement for its photo viewer app with a file explorer called "FilemanCE" using the mfr's slightly modified map update software.

Comment: I DO have the Win Mobile 5.0 SDK.  I noticed something last night:  it doesn't have much in its Windows folder. There is a sticker on it: "Windows CE 5.0 Core", which leads me to believe it has a stripped down version of Windows.  Most all of its functionality is provided by a program called "TNShell", provided by the mfgr.  Is it even possible to run the CE CLR on it?  If not, I wonder if I can write native, unmanaged code for it somehow?  I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: You're right in assuming that your device is running a sort of stripped down version of Windows[CE]. Windows CE is a very loosely designed platform. Mfgrs can build customized versions of Windows CE for their devices using Platform Builder. This allows them to remove unnecessary components (such as Solitaire.exe), add support for custom hardware, and replace UI components to get a custom look. As far as I know you shouldn't have a problem getting Compact Framework 2.0 to run, but there may be some unexpected behavior, when it comes to working with hardware or UI.